# 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native, xcframework

When I am trying to make XCFramework from the famous command line, I am facing the below error:

```
#import "Headers/private_framework.h"
        ^
../private_framework.h:9:9: error: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'private_framework'

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

My private framework project has react-native dependencies. I am on Xcode 12.4.  I have already tried the below steps:

1. Deleted derived data and clean build.
2. Deintegrated pods and did pod install.
3. Using the latest cocoa pod version.
4. sudo Xcode-select --reset.

Comment: Facing the same problem here